# wireguard on debian and commercial provider app problems

Tags: vpn, application, wireguard

EDIT: i did a lot of things with what I received as advices and helps below, but now torguard app works with wireguard protocol, dont know exactly what is the exactly thing which is helped me but thank you very much

I USE torguard as provider, their apps works great but on debian, the problem seems to be wireguard and not their app, cause the app works elsewhere, I think debian and wireguard have problems...?

here the problems: I need wireguard tools to use their vpn app.

```
root @ e6530: / home / xxxx # apt install wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools
Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
wireguard-tools is already the most recent version (1.0.20200827-1 ~ bpo10 + 1).
wireguard-dkms is already the most recent version (1.0.20201221-1 ~ bpo10 + 1).
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 1 not updated.

~$ modprobe wireguard
bash: modprobe : commande introuvable

:~$  sudo wg-quick up wg0
[sudo] Mot de passe de james : 
wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist
```

It seems that The problem here is the app cannot write to ave the private key and wireguard is not supported on your system:

```
Starting "/sbin/ip link add torguard-wg type wireguard""RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported (edited) 

WireGuard: fail creating temporary file for private key

On Tue, Jan 26, 2021 at 1:06 PM TorGuard Support  wrote: Hello, The problem here is the app cannot wite to the temp directory: WireGuard: fail creating temporary file for private key
```

btw, open vpn protocol is ok but wg protocol, failed with that error on the interface :

```
it was not possible to set up vpn interface, an error occured while creating vpn interfaces
```

So., dont know if someone would have some infos, advices, ideas, I reached torguard helpdesk but they have solution... and, it works on linux mint, ubuntu and arch so why not on debian
thanks

Comment: yes yes, wireguard is installed but as you see, yes it is up to date but in same time, I can't have info on wireguard when I do command about it, and the torguard app is also install, cause open vpn protocol is working but not wireguard

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ modprobe wireguard
 bash: modprobe : commande introuvable
```

You should run this command as root:

```
sudo apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
sudo reboot
```

Disable the secure boot as said [@A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b), then run:

To unload mosule:

```
sudo modprobe -rv wireguard
```

To load the module:

```
sudo modprobe -v wireguard
```

ALso you need to create the `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` file.

[WireGuard Server: Debian](https://wireguard.how/server/debian/)

Comment: `ames@e6530:~$ sudo modprobe wireguard
[sudo] Mot de passe de james : 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wireguard': Required key not available`

Comment: here after I did some steps with your link about server:

 `james@e6530:~$ sudo nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
james@e6530:~$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/wg0
james@e6530:~$ sudo ifup wg0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
ifup: failed to bring up wg0
james@e6530:~$ sudo wg show wg0
Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported`

Comment: @James78    I have updated my answer.

Comment: @James78 I can't reproduce any error. All thing work perfectly on a backported kernel.

Comment: UEFI Secure mode prevents loading a a separately compiled kernel module (since the signing key is not available). Try again without Secure mode

Comment: @A.B Good point I will add it ot answer.

Comment: I did it, secure boot, btw , now when I do `modprobe wireguard` I got nothing

ames@e6530:~$ sudo modprobe wireguard
[sudo] Mot de passe de james : 
james@e6530:~$

same thing with sudo modprobe -v wireguard

Comment: see my edit on my question, thanks

Comment: @James78 You can unload then load the module with verbosity: `sudo modprobe -rv wireguard` load it `sudo modprobe wireguard` you should see some `insmod ...`

Comment: @GAD3R at the same time it appears the backports kernel are also signed. So since wireguard is included directly, it's also signed. That when wireguard-dkms is used that this is an issue. I should have written this immediately. Anyway when troubleshooting...

Comment: ok its working now and , btw, yesterday I emailed torguard helpdesk during 5 hours, + chat and no resolution, so again, you are the best, thanks

Comment: @James78 You are welcome again and again.

Comment: one more thing, I need to open torguard via terminal, I have the app on my desktop environnment but if I open from there, all freezes. So I need to open via terminal and even if I add $ at the end `sudo torguard $` if I close the terminal cause I forgot or by mistake, automaticaly, torguard app closes too.........

Comment: @James78 You can run it in background `sudo torguard &`

Comment: running in background yes, to stop or changing server, the problem is that I need to reopen via terminal and restart and disconnect again to stop.... I tried some command in terminal but no result